# Charts.js Pie Chart

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I cannot get the Pie Chart (top right) to load in this Bootstrap Admin theme.

It does load fine until I add in the Information 'Panel' or any other non charts.js panel, and then it will no longer load.

I uploaded the files at the link below, but also included the on page html below.

http://econics.liift.io/Admin/charts-chartjs.html

```html
<!-- .page-content -->
<div class="page-content sidebar-page right-sidebar-page clearfix">
  <!-- .page-content-wrapper -->
  <div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content-inner">
      <!-- Start .page-content-inner -->
      <div id="page-header" class="clearfix">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h2>Chartjs</h2>
          <span class="txt">Nice chart plugin.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="header-stats">
          <div class="spark clearfix">
            <div class="spark-info">
              <span class="number">2345</span>Visitors
            </div>
            <div id="spark-visitors" class="sparkline"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="spark clearfix">
            <div class="spark-info">
              <span class="number">17345</span>Views
            </div>
            <div id="spark-templateviews" class="sparkline"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="spark clearfix">
            <div class="spark-info">
              <span class="number">3700$</span>Sales
            </div>
            <div id="spark-sales" class="sparkline"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Start .row -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <!-- col-lg-6 start here -->
          <div class="panel panel-default toggle panelMove panelClose panelRefresh">
            <!-- Start .panel -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">Line chart with Dots</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="canvas-holder">
                <canvas id="line-dots-chartjs" height="200"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End .panel -->
          <div class="panel panel-default toggle panelMove panelClose panelRefresh">
            <!-- Start .panel -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">Line chart unfilled<small>and curved</small></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="canvas-holder">
                <canvas id="line-unfilled-chartjs" height="100"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End .panel -->
          <div class="panel panel-default toggle panelMove panelClose panelRefresh">
            <!-- Start .panel -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">Line chart</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="canvas-holder">
                <canvas id="line-chartjs" height="100"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End .panel -->
        </div>
        <!-- col-lg-6 end here -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <!-- col-lg-6 start here -->
          <div class="panel panel-default toggle panelMove panelClose panelRefresh">
            <!-- Start .panel -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">Pie Chart</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="canvas-holder">
                <canvas id="pie-chartjs" height="100"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End .panel -->
          <div class="panel panel-default toggle panelMove panelClose panelRefresh">
            <!-- Start .panel -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">Information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="canvas-holder">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <h1>This is an H1 heading</h1>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                  <h2>This is an H2 heading</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                  <h3>This is an H3 heading</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                  <h4>This is an H4 heading</h4>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                  <h5>This is an H5 heading</h5>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                  <h6>This is an H6 heading</h6>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End .panel -->
        </div>
        <!-- col-lg-6 end here -->
      </div>
      <!-- End .row -->
    </div>
    <!-- End .page-content-inner -->
  </div>
  <!-- / page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- / page-content -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the inspector.  You'll see you are throwing an error on `line 293` of charts-chartjs.js.

`[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("bar-chartjs").getContext')`

The code for your pie chart comes after this, so the pie chart code isn't ran.

Edit - Add code for checking if element exists.
`getElementById` returns `null` if the element doesn't exist.  So, you can wrap your creation of the chart in a simple if statement:

```
var bar = document.getElementById("bar-chartjs");
var ctxBar;
if (bar) {
    ctxBar = bar.getContext("2d");
    myBar = new Chart(ctxBar).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true,
        scaleShowGridLines : true,
        scaleGridLineColor : "#bfbfbf",
        scaleGridLineWidth : 0.2,
        //bar options
        barShowStroke : true,
        barStrokeWidth : 2,
        barValueSpacing : 5,
        barDatasetSpacing : 2,
        //animations
        animation: true,
        animationSteps: 60,
        animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",
        //scale
        showScale: true,
        scaleFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
        scaleFontSize: 13,
        scaleFontStyle: "normal",
        scaleFontColor: "#333",
        scaleBeginAtZero : true,
        //tooltips
        showTooltips: true,
        tooltipFillColor: "#344154",
        tooltipFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
        tooltipFontSize: 13,
        tooltipFontColor: "#fff",
        tooltipYPadding: 8,
        tooltipXPadding: 10,
        tooltipCornerRadius: 2,
        tooltipTitleFontFamily: "'Roboto'",
    });
}
```

Comment: I removed bar chart from the js file and now it works. Am I correct to think that this because I removed the Bar Chart from the page thus I also should have also removed from chart-chartjs.js?

Comment: Yes, it was trying to find an element with the id of bar-chartjs and then run a function on it without checking if it existed.  So, removing the call from the js will make the errors go away.  But, if you want to make the javascript more flexible, you can check if the element exists before trying to call getContext